# How could I find a function $f: \Bbb {R}\rightarrow\Bbb {R}$ so that $Y=f(X)$ has the given probability density?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable that is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0, 1]$.

How could I find a fucntion $f: \Bbb {R}\rightarrow\Bbb {R}$ so that $Y=f(X)$ has a probability density given by $g_Y(y)=1/y^2$ when $y\geqslant 1$  and everywhere else $g_Y(y)=0$?

I know that for a uniform distribution you get the function $f(x)=1/(\beta-\alpha)$ for $\alpha\leqslant x \leqslant \beta$. So I guess that for variable $X$, $f(x)=1$.

Comment: I would immediately try something like $f(X) = 1/X$, just to make the interval correct.

Comment: Or look at the cdf, this may help... $\mathbb{P}\{ Y \leq y \} = \int_1^y \frac{du}{u^2} = 1- \frac{1}{y} = \mathbb{P}\{ X\in[\frac{1}{y},1] \}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: This is called [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)  in statistics.